# multiple array iteration in multiple threads to add

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, thread-synchronization

I have a simple **Computer** class with 3 fields and **Computers** class which has Computer[] array and sortedAdd method, which adds elements to internal array in a sorted manner.

In main method I have **computers** array which has all records from the files I've read and **results** variable to which I'm trying to add all records by iterating through each **Computers** class object in **computers** array.

In main method I want to run a selected amount of threads (2 <= amount <= 7) - which will iterate through all the records I have and will add each of them to results. My Computers class needs to be thread-safe also.

I've tried this and it seems to be working, but only if I use 3 threads (which is obvious because I'm assigning one thread to one Computers object).

```
    public class Computers
    {
        public Computer[] _computers; //stores 'Computer' class objects.

        private readonly object _locker;
        public int _count { get; private set; } //element in array count

        public Computers(int length)
        {
            _locker = new object();
            _count = 0;
            _computers = new Computer[length];
        }

        public void sortedAdd(Computer computer)
        {
            lock (_locker)
            {
                int indexToinsert = findIndex(computer); // find a spot where element should be added
                if (indexToinsert == 0 && _count == 0 || indexToinsert == _count)
                {
                    _computers[indexToinsert] = computer;
                    _count++;
                }
                else
                {   //free up space for the element to be added.
                    for (int i = _count; i > indexToinsert; i--)
                    {
                        _computers[i] = _computers[i - 1];
                    }
                    _computers[indexToinsert] = computer;
                    _count++;
                }
                Monitor.Pulse(_locker);
            }

        }

        public int findIndex(Computer computer)
        {

            if (_count == 0)
                return 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < _count; i++)
            {
                if (computer.CompareTo(_computers[i]) <= 0)
                {
                    return i;
                }
            }
            return _count;
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Computers[] computers = new Computers[3]; //data stored from 3 files.
        Computers results = new Computers(90); // will store all elements here.

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            computers[i] = ReadToArray(); //each Computers object's array Computer[] is populated with 30 records.




        // --- now we take each element and add it to results.
        var threadsAdd = Enumerable.Range(0, 3).Select(i => new Thread(() =>
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < computers[i]._computers.Length; j++)
            {
                results.sortedAdd(computers[i]._computers[j]);
            }
        }));

        var threads = threadsAdd.ToList();

        foreach (var thread in threads)
        {
            thread.Start();
        }
        // wait for all threads to finish
        foreach (var thread in threads)
        {
            thread.Join();
        }
    }
```

How do I do the same but with.. for example 2, 4 or 5 threads instead ?
Also is my Computers class thread safe?

Edit: I need to use Thread class specifically and not allowed to use thread safe collections

Comment: I would ditch the `Thread` class and focus your attention on *Tasks*, then use *TPL Parallel* methods, and a *thread safe collection.* most of your complexity goes away

Comment: @TheGeneral Well I'm asking this because I'm supposed to use Thread class and not allowed to use thread safe collections.